# Tensorflow tensor of filenames

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to create a tensor of filenames in order to create a dataset with the Dataset API. My code is `tf.convert_to_tensor(file_list)`. I have also tried `tf.constant(file_list)` with similar results. In this case, `file_list` is a Python 1-d list of filename strings. This returns a tensor of shape `(N, )` where `N` is the number of files. `np.rank` tells me it is a rank 0 tensor with dtype `tf.int32`. Even specifying the dtype, `tf.convert_to_tensor(file_list, dtype=tf.string)` produces the same result.

When I pass this to the a Dataset object using `Datset.from_tensor_slices` and call `dataset.map`, I get an error with read_file stating that the rank of the input is rank-1 when it should be rank-0. This seems to imply to me that either the conversion to tensor somehow creates a tensor of strange shape or the `Datset.from_tensor_slices` reads in the data in an unexpected manner.

Code:

```
    dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.convert_to_tensor(file_list))
    dataset = self.dataset.map(_input_parser)

def _input_parser(filename):
    filename
    image = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(filename))
    return image
```

Comment: Have you tried `Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_list)` ? `from_tensor_slices` works on normal lists for me.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified my code somewhat for this post. My input data is actually a list of dicts which I convert into a dict of lists. In order to pass this to `from_tensor_slices`, I have to convert the values in the dict to tensors.

Comment: You don't have to convert it to tensors. Just take the values  inside your  dict and put them in a list. You'll get a list of string. You should then be able to feed this list directly to `from_tensor_slices`